# Results locale from Cloud Vision API using TEXT_DETECTION

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm using `npm node-cloud-vision-api`

API correctly detects language of the document but the results characters are returned in western character subset not corresponding to a locale. I assume they should be returned in UTF-8 characters but all the locale specific characters are mapped into basic western character subset.

For example:

`Wartosc` is return insted of `Wartość`

How to instruct the API to return correct UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Is this issue fixed? Have you tried [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/python/text)?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried passing in a language hint to the OCR Detection call. Please follow the below API Reference. https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#AnnotateImageRequest

Answer (score 2):

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303473/google-cloud-vision-api-text-detection) it is a known issue with the Cloud Vision API when you don't use language hints.

You can see the actual bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/detail?id=50).