# Google Cloud Vision API - TEXT_DETECTION

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

When i try to recognize a text in image, like the italian word "Perchè", Vision API get back the word "Perche" (give back the "e" and not the correct one "è").

I don't want to use languageHints to try to obtain better results because i've to do OCR Recognition across different language.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known issue with the Cloud Vision API when you don't use language hints.

You can see the actual bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/detail?id=50).

It is in state `accepted`, but there seems to be radio silence on it for the last few months. It may take some time to roll it out.